# Find and update(append) csv with shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

Input file:

```
ID,Name,Values 
1,A,vA|A2
2,B,VB
```

Expected output:

```
1,A,vA|VA2|vA3
2,B,VB
```

Search file for a given ID and then append a given value in the values {field}

*use case : append 'testvalue' to the values filed of ID = 1*

Problem is : How tho cache the line found ?

`sed`'s `s` can be used to substitution, I used `sed`'s `p` {print but of no use }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `n` to ID of the row you want to update and `x` to the value:

```
# vA3 to entry with ID==1
$ awk -F, '$1==n{$0=$0"|"x}1' n=1 x="vA3" file
ID,Name,Values
1,A,vA|A2|vA3
2,B,VB

# TEST_VALUE to entry with ID==2
$ awk -F, '$1==x{$0=$0"|"v}1' x=2 v="TEST_VALUE" file
ID,Name,Values
1,A,vA|A2
2,B,VB|TEST_VALUE
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F,` sets the field separator to be a comma.
- `$1==x` checks if the line we are looking at contains the ID we want to change. Where `$1` is the first field on each line and `x` is the variable we define.
- If the previous condition was true then follow block gets executed `{$0=$0"|"v}` where `$0` is the variable containing the whole line so we are just appending the string `"|"` and value of the variable `v` to end of the line.
- The trailing `1` is just a shortcut in `awk` to say print the line. The `1` is the condition for the block which is evaluated to true and since no block is provide `awk` executes the default block `{print $0}`. Explicitly the script would be `awk -F, '$1==n{$0=$0"|"x}{print $0}' n=1 x="vA3" file`.

Comment: A brief explanation will be helpful

Comment: Funny I was thinking the same thing about your question. See the edit, I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The following script is doing something similar to Your need. It is in pure `bash`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
[ $# -ne 2 ] && echo "Arg missing" && exit 1;
while read l; do
   [ ${l%%,*} == "$1" ] && l="$l|$2"
   echo $l
done <infile
```

You can use as `script <ID> <VALUE>`. Example:

```
$ ./script 1 va3
ID,Name,Values
1,A,vA|A2|va3
2,B,VB
$ cat infile
ID,Name,Values 
1,A,vA|A2
2,B,VB
```

Answer (score 1):

are your looking for this?

```
kent$ echo "1,A,vA
2,B,VB"|sed '/vA/s/$/|VA2/'
1,A,vA|VA2
2,B,VB
```

**EDIT** check the ID, then replace

```
kent$  echo "ID,Name,Values 
1,A,vA|A2
2,B,VB"|sed 's/^1,.*/&|vA3/'
ID,Name,Values 
1,A,vA|A2|vA3
2,B,VB
```

`&` means the matched part. that would be what you meant "cache"

Comment: @saurabhshashank check the EDIT in answer

Answer (score 1):

or may be this?

```
awk '/vA/ { $NF=$NF"|VA2" } 1' FS=, OFS=,


$ echo "1,A,vA
2,B,VB" | awk '/vA/ { $NF=$NF"|VA2" } 1'  FS=, OFS=,
1,A,vA|VA2
2,B,VB
```

#### Edit 1: `awk` started supporting in-file substitution recently. But with your requirement it is best to go with `sed` solution that Kent has posted above.

```
$ cat file
ID,Name,Values
1,A,vA|A2
2,B,VB

$ awk '$1==1 { $NF=$NF"|vA3" } 1' FS=, OFS=, file
ID,Name,Values
1,A,vA|A2|vA3
2,B,VB
```

Answer (score 0):

sed ' 1 a\ |VA2|vA3 ' file1.txt

Comment: Try to Explain your Answer.